# Does exist a SD card disk array?

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage, raid, raid-controller

I need a disk array like those which we can just add a new hard disk but using sd cards rather than disk. Does it exist?

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/HP_EVA4400-1.jpg/440px-HP_EVA4400-1.jpg (something like this but with sd cards or micro sd cards)

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Baoblaze-Converter-Module-Micro-Adapter/dp/B07BJZBQWL/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=10+x+micro+SD+to+SATA+SSD+Adapter&qid=1567392123&s=gateway&sr=8-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could buy a [4-port SD card hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EJ8CKRU) for ~US$63.

However, you could easily make your own: [SD card readers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FFY5640) are available for less than $US2, and a [4-port USB hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PDBNVGN) for ~US$6, so you could assemble a similar 4-SD card hub for

You don't state your purpose, so it's hard to understand what you need.

- If you're trying to make copies of SD cards, e.g. as OS for a batch o microprocessors, there are [SD drive duplicators](https://www.amazon.com/slp/sd-card-duplicator/y4dqz8gwsbgc4gn).
- If you're trying to simulate a "drive carousel" or [CD/DVD array](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000069JWX), be aware that flash memory is much slower than SDD or HDD, and more expensive than HDD. A large HDD could be partitioned into a virtual array of disks.

Comment: I got you beat... https://the-gadgeteer.com/2016/03/17/turn-10-micro-sd-cards-into-a-sata-ssd-drive/    or https://www.amazon.com/1Pack-Micro-Memory-Adapter-Converter/dp/B01MU59ACL/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1509538124&sr=8-2&keywords=10+x+micro+SD+to+SATA+SSD+Adapter+&+RAID+Quad+2.5%22+SATA+Converter&dpID=51aZ7RZ500L&preST=_SY300_QL70_&dpSrc=srch&linkCode=sl1&tag=thegadg0e-20&linkId=a96d41c20aa1a8d9e7687458bb289e38   It can hold 10 micro SD cards at once.

Comment: @cybernard Unavailable though.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths https://www.amazon.com/FidgetFidget-Micro-Memory-Adapter-Converter/dp/B07MGBHBJN/ref=sr_1_26?keywords=10+sd+card+sata&qid=1567555580&s=gateway&sr=8-26